# .net string.reverse length value

Tags: .net

Can anyone tell me why the length of the string returned by the below method is always 60? This is a C# method in a console application.

```
static string Reverse(string stringToReverse)
{
    string s = stringToReverse.Reverse().ToString();
    return s;
}
```

We ask interview candidates to write a method to reverse a string as part of the job hire process. This is one answer that we got. The length issue has us wondering.

Comment: Great answers everyone. Its very simplate really. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the method fundamentally won't work. It's using LINQ to treat `stringToReverse` as an `IEnumerable<char>` which is the reversed... but calling `ToString` on the `IEnumerable<char>` returned by `Reverse()` *won't* do what's wanted here. Don't look at the length - look at the string itself! (A single unit test for this would prove the point, of course.)

The obvious fix for this is something like:

```
return new string(stringToReverse.Reverse().ToArray());
```

... but this still won't actually do the right thing, due to Unicode combining characters, surrogate pairs etc. Actually reversing a string *properly* would be pretty involved... certainly not something I'd expect to see done correctly during an interview, but the awareness that it's harder than you might think would be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Because the result of:

```
stringToReverse.Reverse().ToString()
```

is:

```
"System.Linq.Enumerable+<ReverseIterator>d__a0`1[System.Char]"
```

Instead of the reversed content of the string. This is because the `string` is seen as an `IEnumerable<char>` by the `Reverse()` method, and calling `ToString()` on this collection will give you the string representation of the collection, rather than of its contents.

Comment: So how do you turn the reverse iterator into the reversed string?

Comment: See the answer by @Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the resulting string?

> System.Linq.Enumerable+d__a0`1[System.Char]

Your candidate used the LinQ Reverse method to create a enumeration, but failed to realize that the Enumerable cannot be transferred to a string by calling .ToString().

One possible way would be to create a new string from a char array:

```
static string Reverse(string stringToReverse)
{
  return new string(stringToReverse.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```